# Connect to AWS Neptune server via nginx as proxy

Tags: nginx, amazon-neptune

AWS Neptune is private to VPC. We can't access it from outside the VPC. So I created one instance in the same VPC and installed nginx in it. I configured nginx like this (side config parts skipped).

```
http {
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  sendfile            on;
  #tcp_nopush          on;
  tcp_nodelay         on;
  keepalive_timeout   65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  server {
    listen 8182;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/neptune.error.log main;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/neptune.access.log main;
    location / {
      proxy_pass <neptune_endpoint>:8182;
    }
  }
}
```

When I tried to access Neptune, every time I am getting this error.

```
{"requestId":"","code":"BadRequestException","detailedMessage":"Bad request."}
```

If anybody faced this kind of issue, please help me out.

Comment: Hi @SV Madhava Reddy - I have not used Nginx before for this but I have used ALB, NLB and SSH tunnel. Whenever I hit this kind of issue the first thing I try is to see if I can `curl <neptune_endpoint>:8182/status`

If you SSH to the EC2 instance where Nginx is running does that curl work from there? If it does not you may need to check your Security Group settings for port 8182.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although AWS Neptune has http endpoint, while I tried with nginx, it didn't work. So I tried different directives that nginx is offering. And **stream** directive is the one I wanted. Posting answer if anybody needs the same solution in future.

```
stream {
  server {
    listen 8182;
    proxy_pass <neptune_endpoint>:8182;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

can you give this one a try and see if it works? I gave it a quick test and it seems to work ok.

```
http {
        upstream neptune {
                server <neptune_endpoint_without_protocol>:8182;
                keepalive 15;
        }

        sendfile            on;
        tcp_nodelay         on;
        keepalive_timeout   65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server {
                listen 8182;
                error_log  /var/log/nginx/neptune.error.log;
                access_log  /var/log/nginx/neptune.access.log;
                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://neptune;
                        proxy_redirect off;
                        proxy_buffering off;

                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
                        proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. But Aws Neptune is having http endpoint. But if you are working with nginx to route, then you have to use stream directive. I will post my answer now. Thanks.